# .NET Core 3.1 with PostreSQL jsonb JsonDocument mapping not working because "The LINQ expression could not be translated"

Tags: c#, json, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I tried following [Npgsql tutorial](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cjsondocument) regarding accessing json DOM via dynamic mapping. What is suggested in the tutorial is to use `JsonDocument` and then use `.GetProperty(string)` on it, but it seems that it's only accessible via `.RootElement` (which is a `JsonElement`, and it does contain `GetProperty` method).

Either way, I get this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<GameEntity>
.Where(g => g.GameInfo.GetProperty("ReadableIdentifier").ToString() == __readableIdentifier_0)' 
could not be translated. 
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly 
by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

I have tried few solutions:

1. Works: Adding `AsEnumerable()` to the query, but this defeats the purpose, as it gets all the data without actually accessing JSON data natively
2. Works: changing to POCO instead - but this greatly limits the flexibility I want from the JSON Document
3. Doesn't work: removing `services.AddNewtonsoftJson(...)` from `ConfigureServices(...)` in `Startup`, as that was needed for the controller responses to set `options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling`
4. Doesn't work: Dereferencing Newtonsoft.Json (I am using Swagger and it seems to require it).

Ideally, I would love to see the query below work natively and with proper translation, without need to download all records before doing the operations:

```
var gameEntity = _context.Games
            .Include(x => x.Characters)
            //.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x.GameInfo.GetProperty("ReadableIdentifier").ToString() == readableIdentifier)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there anything I miss?

Comment: This should be tagged C# and EF Core, not anything else! This issue is well explained in the EF Core documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval

Comment: Hey @CoolBots, thank you for the response. Can I ask you for the source?

Comment: I edited my initial comment to add the link to the document. Basically, the LINQ query must be translatable to SQL (client-side evaluation). You'll need to re-write your query. The page I linked has examples as well - look at the *Unsupported client evaluation* section of that document.

Comment: My apologies, but I feel like you have skipped the link I have sent. Npgsql reference is stating something very similar in their documentation as an example, so is it really that bad with my query?

Comment: I think it's the `GetProperty` call that's causing the error; I don't have  time at the moment to look into it deeper, but I did miss that link; I removed my downvote, as I see where the rationale for the rest of your tags is based on.